# How can I capture and combine video which streams through short MP4 segments?

Tags: video, streaming

I'm streaming some video on a certain website, and was hoping to save the stream to a file. Using my browser's Developer Tools console, I see that network-wise, the player client downloads short .mp4 segments, which likely correspond to different stretches of time in the film.

My question: How can I easily: (1) Save all of these and (2) Match them up and combine them so that I get continuous video and audio for the entire duration?

Note: I'm using Devuan Beowulf (= Debian Buster without systemd)

Comment: Or you could just stream the video and audio to a file, https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream/ If you can't stream directly from the web to VLC, you could still capture screen output from your browser.

Comment: @user10191234: 1. How would I know which files belong to which stream? 2. The files might not fit in the cache and be overwritten by newer segments? 3. It's a Windows-only utility :-(

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I don't have a URL for just the stream. If I had that, life would be easy. I have a web page with some (Javascript?) client which pulls small files at different points in time.